# How does assigning a string to int and passing that int to printf prints the string properly?

Tags: c, string, int, printf

Why does this work? (i.e how is passing `int` to `printf()` results in printing the string)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n="String";
    printf("%s",n);
    return 0;
}
```

> warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
>    int n="String";
>   warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>    printf("%s",n);

Output:String

compiler:gcc 4.8.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code,

```
  int n="String";  //conversion of pointer to integer
```

is highly-implementation dependent <sup>note 1</sup>

and

```
 printf("%s",n);   //passing incompatible type of argument
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). <sup>note 2</sup>
 **Don't do that**.

**Moral of the story:** The warnings are there for a reason, pay heed to them.

---

**Note 1:**

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. [....]

**Note 2:**

chapter §7.21.6.1

> [....] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

and for the type of argument for `%s` format specifier with `printf()`

> `s` If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a **pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.** [...]

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

Essentially, you're assigning a `const char*` to an `int`, and the `printf` converts it back. But do regard that as entirely coincidental: you're not allowed to cast unrelated types like that.

C gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: This reminds me of something cited by Bjarne Stroustrup: _C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot. C++ makes it harder, but when you do, it blows away your whole leg._ :)

Answer (score 1):

`int` type can store 4 bytes numbers on most today's computers (from -2147483647 to 2147483647)

Which means it ""can"" store SOME address as well, only problem is when your address is bigger than 2147483647 it will cause overflow and you will not be able to get the address, (which is very bad for your program obviously)

An address is a number referring to memory space,
Pointers are made to store addresses, they are larger (8 bytes on 64bits systems, 4 bytes on 32bits systems) and they are also unsigned (only positive)

which means, when you affect `int n="String";` if the address to `"String"`  is under 2147483647 it wont cause issues and you code will run (DONT DO THAT)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm

now if you think about it, you can guess why there is a 4GB ram limit on 32bit systems

(sorry about possible english mistakes, I m french)

Comment: "int type can store 4 bytes numbers on most today's systems". I don't agree. I believe that -32768 to +32767 is still most common if you include embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with options like `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wint-to-pointer-cast -pedantic` (GCC) will show you very quickly that this behaviour should not be relied upon.